# Setting the element class in html element created by javascript

Tags: javascript

I am creating a html table by javascript, but I can't set the class name to these elements.

What I want: clicking on the one of the inputs in the second column activates function. For example, this function set the `<p>` color to red.

I was trying many solutions, but it's still not working.

HTML:

```
<div id="table"></div> 
<p id="a">adasd</p>
```

JS:

```
var arr = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"];

var table = "<table><tr><td><b>Test</b></td>";
table += "<td style='width: 50px'>RN</td>";
table += "<td style='width: 50px'>MW</td></tr>";

for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    table += "<td>" + arr[i] + "</td>";
    table += "<td><input class='rn' style='width: 50px'></input></td>";
    table += "<td><input style='width: 50px'></input></td></tr>";
}

table += "</table>";

document.querySelectorAll('.rn').onclick = function() {change()};

function change() {
    document.getElementById("a").style.color = "red";
}
document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = table;
```

Comment: does the answer solve your problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run `onclick` with `querySelectorAll`, here is my simple solution. I just added `onclick='change()'`

```js
var arr = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"];

var table = "<table><tr><td><b>Test</b></td>";
table += "<td style='width: 50px'>RN</td>";
table += "<td style='width: 50px'>MW</td></tr>";

for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    table += "<td>" + arr[i] + "</td>";
    table += "<td><input class='rn' style='width: 50px' onclick='change()' ></input></td>";
    table += "<td><input style='width: 50px'></input></td></tr>";
}

table += "</table>";


function change() {

    document.getElementById("a").style.color = "red";
}
document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = table;
```

```html
<div id="table"></div> 
<p id="a">adasd</p>
```